# Linux script to copy specific range of data from a webpage to a text file

Tags: linux, range, extract

I am looking for code to extract a range of data from a webpage.
The webpage is:

http://kos.hdsat.pl/menu-20.html

The range of data I am interested in is the Oscam.srvid data (The first list of data on the page).
I would like to copy this data to a local file called Oscam.srvid

Another option would be to get the script to tcck the box for the package and select the Oscam.srvid button at the top of the page.

I am not sure which option would be easiest to script but either would work fine for me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wget` to download the html website and then `sed` to extract the content you want to use. Something like

```
wget http://kos.hdsat.pl/menu-20.html && sed -n '/<textarea/,${/<\/textarea/q; s/<.*>//g; p}' menu-20.html > Oscam.srvid
```

could do the job.

What's happening here?

`wget http://kos.hdsat.pl/menu-20.html` downloads the file, if that's successful we run `sed` but suppressing all output with the option `-n`. Now we look for the first occurrence of "textarea" and print til the end of the document (`$`; we don't actually print to the end of the document but rather have a quit statement later on). In these lines we run the following `sed` commands:

`/<\/textarea/q` to quit as soon as we find "<\textarea".
`s/<.*>//g` to remove all <> brackets, i.e. HTML tags.
`p` to print all the lines, since we suppressed output.

This worked for me on the website, but could fail if the website changes. For instance, if there's another `<textarea>` element introduced before the one we are actually looking for, it will extract the content of this `<textarea>`. One could then refine the `sed` command by searching for `Oscam.srvid` or something similar.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer & even more so for the explanation.  Worked perfectly!